# How to merge two lists of objects into 1 list of objects while also merging the objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, javascript-objects

The title may sound more complicated than it is.

I have 2 arrays, created by two different maps. I then proceed to loop through each array like so:

```
let temp = [];
    let temp2 = [];

    nameArray.forEach(function(x){
        temp.push({question: x[0]})
    })
    bodyArray.forEach(function(x){
        temp2.push({answer: x[0]})
    })
```

giving me the outcome of:

```
[0:{question: "generic question"}
 1:{question:...}
 2:{...}]
```

and:

```
[0:{answer: "generic answer"}
 1:{answer:...}
 2:{...}]
```

what I'm look to get in the end is a single list of objects, and have the objects be the objects from the two arrays, but merged like so:

```
[0:{question: "generic question", answer: "generic answer"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array#map` and iterate through your question array and by using the index of `question` array you can add element from your `answer` array and generate the array of object with both question and answer.

```js
const questions = ["generic question", "generic question 12", "generic question 34"],
      answers = ["generic answer", "generic answer 12", "generic answer 34"];

const merged = questions.map((question, i) => ({question, 'answer' : answers[i]}));
console.log(merged);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate each over each of the `questions` and merge them using `.forEach()`:

```
let questions = [
{question: "Question?"},
{question: "Question 2"},
];

let answers = [
{answer: "Yes"},
{answer: "no"}
];

questions.forEach((question, i) => question["answer"] = Object.values(answers[i])[0]);
```

Which outputs:

```
 [ 0: {question: "Question?", answer: "Yes"},
1: {question: "Question 2", answer: "no"} ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an arbitrary count of properties and the wanted arrays for it and build new objects.

```js
var questions = ['question1', 'question2', 'question3'],
    answers = ['answer1', 'answer2', 'answer3'],
    keys = ['question', 'answer'],
    result = [questions, answers].reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        a.forEach(function (v, j) {
            r[j] = r[j] || {};
            r[j][keys[i]] = v;
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```